# Formula for the area of the surface obtained by revolving the curve $y = f(x)$ about the line $y = -k$

Tags: calculus

Assume $f$ is continuous and $f(x)\geq 0$ for $a\leq x\leq b$. Derive a formula of the area of the surface obtained by revolving the curve $y=f(x)$ , $a\leq x\leq b$ about line $y=-k$ ($k>0$).

Comment: What have you tried? Have you, for instance, tried doing it with the constant function $f(x) = 1$ and see what you get?

Comment: Surface Area = $\int_{a}^{b}2pif(x)sqrt(1+f'(x)^2)dx$, but it is revolving f(x) about x axis. And how to revolve f(x) about line y=-k?

Comment: If you revolve $f(x) + k$ around the $x$-axis, you get the exact same figure as when you revolve $f(x)$ around $y = -k$.

Comment: thx arthur, u help me so much!